# django-allauth) How to get access token from access code in url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm trying to add social login to my django-rest-framework app, but I'm stuck on this problem and need some help.

I used `django-allauth` to get `code`, which is used to get `access token`.

Login Flow: Request code(GET) -> Response -> Request token(POST) -> Response

[API reference here](https://developers.kakao.com/docs/restapi/user-management)

So, after I log in to social account,(e.g. Facebook)click `authorize my app` button, I get access code like this :

```
"GET /accounts/kakao/login/callback/?code=1cH2huI2SuGuZxY4wYHU8hieeIXAhhL_XTpTqdR0g5DV1Zn8smcGzheW4IqakEEzNshfMAo9dVoAAAFqzwxacQ&state=uqTv1puHiHuy HTTP/1.1" 200 487
```

But I just don't know how to get access token from this url! Should I make new view class inside of my view.py file? should I make a new url for getting access token??

Comment: I am not sure but I think maybe python requests can solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think we need your view to answer this question but i think this maybe work:

add a view like this to `views.py`:

```
def social_login(request):
    token = request.GET["code"]
    """Do Some Thing"""
```

add this to your `url.py`:

```
path('/accounts/kakao/login/callback', views.social_login)
```